# Webpage with open graph metadata as a valid place for FB Check-ins

Tags: web, facebook-opengraph, facebook-checkins

I'm trying to publish check-ins to places that aren't available on Facebook. I created a sample web page for a sample place and added the open graph metadata, but Facebook doesn't recognize my "og:type" correctly; it always crawls my page as an "og:type" "website", which marks my place-related metadata (e.g. latitude, longitude, city) as extraneous properties and, consequently, makes my page ID as an incorrect ID for a check-in.

My question is: how can I make my web page "represent" a place in "Facebook compliant" open graph metadata? How can I make a web page that is a valid check-in place?

This is the og metadata that I'm using:

```
<html version="XHTML+RDFa 1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="pt" lang="pt" dir="ltr">
    <head>      
        <title>A Bateira</title>    
        <meta content="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4152/5095614606_f6620d7b54.jpg" property="og:image" />    
        <meta content="40.643696" property="og:latitude" /> 
        <meta property="og:type" content="cafe" />  
        <meta content="-8.655696" property="og:longitude" />
        <meta property="og:street-address" content="Cais dos Botiroes" />
        <meta property="og:locality" content="Aveiro" />    
        <meta property="og:region" content="Aveiro" />  
        <meta property="og:postal-code" content="3810" />       
    </head>
```

Best Regards,
P.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently write checking to Open Graph Places (i.e URLs)

At the moment you *can* check a user in to a Facebook place by POSTing to:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?place_id=FACEBOOK_PLACE_ID&access_token=TOKEN&coordinates=COORDS_JSON_OBJ

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ You need the publish_checkins permission for this.

This may change in the future, as checkins are becomming an annotation of the post object.

In the meantime, you can create a custom Cafe object and a custom Checkin action and post your own custom checkin actions to your own custom lat/long-tagged objects